# PDO stored procedure call

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

Okay, not too sure what I've done wrong, but I am having problems running a stored procedure using PDO.  The procedure looks a little like this and runs perfectly as a stand alone.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[user_UserAdd]
            @FirstName      nvarchar(100),
            @Surname        nvarchar(100),
            @EMail          nvarchar(200),
            @Password       nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @UserId     uniqueidentifier
SET     @UserId = NEWID()

INSERT INTO user_Data
VALUES  (@UserId,
         @FirstName,
         @Surname,
         @EMail,
         @Password)

END
```

I know that the database connection works correctly as a select query returns the correct answers.

My php file contains the following :-

```
$stpro = $conn->prepare('EXECUTE user_UserAdd ?, ?, ?, ?');
$stpro->bindParam(1, $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stpro->bindParam(2, $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stpro->bindParam(3, $email, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 200);
$stpro->bindParam(4, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);

// call the stored procedure
$returnvalue = $stpro->execute();

if (!$returnvalue)
{
    return $stpro->errorInfo();
}
```

This always returns the same error message

```
 ["2"] = "An invalid PHP type was specified as an output parameter. 
 DateTime objects, NULL values, and streams cannot be specified as output parameters."
```

I have changed EXECUTE to just EXEC and to CALL and just get the same message.  On checking the database it is definitely not inserting the new line of data, but at the same time the php page loads properly and does not kick any error messages regarding the stored procedure not running.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question back, but have you tried to use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`?

Comment: I maybe off the mark from a quick glance but it appears your stored procedure isn't actually returning anything - therefore the result of the last query will be returned ... but that's an INSERT query so your "output parameter" is NULL?

Comment: @hakre, I have and that just returns the error ["2"] = "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error"

Comment: @CD001 I have tried adding a "Return 1" at the end and this makes no difference.  I'd be loathed to do that either as all of the stored procedures have been written and work perfectly in asp.net.  It's enough of a problem changing the entire site to PHP.  lol

Comment: Was a bit of a longshot I have to admit - I'm not that familiar with MS SQL Server procedures... annoyingly I've managed to just cobble together exactly the same thing with MySQL and it works fine. The INSERT inside the procedure simply returns `(bool) true` if the INSERT succeeds. If I deliberately break the query inside the procedure by entering a non-existent column I just get `(bool) false` with details in `$stpro->errorInfo()` ... not much help here I'm afraid; from what I can see of your code it **should** work :|

Comment: ... hmm actually - how are you defining the parameters for the procedure, the closest thing I got to your error was when I tried assigning the parameters as `INOUT` rather than just `IN` to see how it would break. Then I Googled your error message and found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameter

Comment: Thanks for looking @CD001.  Just know it's going to end up being something really stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound like a binding error , although code looks correct.

You can try binding without specifying the type and leave it up to PDO:

```
$query = "EXECUTE user_UserAdd :firstname, :surname, :email, :password";
$stpro = $conn->prepare($query);
$stpro->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stpro->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
$stpro->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stpro->bindParam(':password', $password);

// call the stored procedure
$returnvalue = $stpro->execute();
```

Or just don't bind at all and see if it works:

```
$query = "EXECUTE user_UserAdd :firstname, :surname, :email, :password";
$stpro = $conn->prepare($query);

// call the stored procedure
$returnvalue = $stpro->execute(array(
                                    ':firstname'=> $firstname,
                                    ':surname'=> $surname,
                                    ':email'=> $email,
                                    ':password'=> $password,     
             ));
```

Comment: To the person who marked this down....why?  This actually works.  As soon as I too the types out it worked.  Crazy and annoying why it didn't work, but @meda, massive thank you.